# Example : product of two non Riemann integrable functions is Riemann integrabe.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Give an example that the product of two non Riemann integrable functions is Riemann integrabe.

Comment: More examples at [a very similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906712).

Answer (score 3):

Try $1_\mathbb Q$ and $1-1_\mathbb Q$ on $[0,1]$, say.

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x)=\frac 1 x$  then $f$ isn't integrable on  $(1,+\infty)$ but $f^2$ is integrable.

Comment: No, the Riemann integral is for bounded intervals $[a,b]$.  Of course it would have been better if the OP had said that.

Comment: $f^2$ in my  example is a generalized Riemann integrable function.