# If the product $fg$ is Riemann integrable then are $f$ and $g$ individually integrable?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If $fg$ is integrable, does this imply that $f$ and $g$ are both integrable too?

I don't need a proof, if someone knows please just say (this will help me understand a thing about Taylor's theorem).

Comment: Consider the function $f$ defined by  $f(x)=1$ for irrational $x$, $f(x)=-1$ for rational $x$. Take $g=f$.

Comment: More examples at [a very similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535957).

Answer (score 3):

No. Since we may define the piecewise function on $(0,1)$, for example, \begin{eqnarray}f = \left\{\begin{array}{lr} 1/x&x\le1/2 \\ 1-x & x>1/2 \end{array} \right.\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}g = \left\{\begin{array}{lr} x&x\le1/2 \\ \frac{1}{1-x} & x>1/2 \end{array} \right.\end{eqnarray}
Then it's obvious that $fg=1$, but both are not integrable.

Comment: This was a proof!

Answer (score 2):

Several other examples are given here (and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535957)), but I will add one more:

Let $f$ be any non-integrable function, and let $g=0$.

Comment: I like this one !